# Pandas: New column value includes entire row

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following code that is going row by row and translating a specific column into English from my dataframe, but when I run it, the resulting new column 'translatedv4'. I am new to looping through entire dataframes rather than lists so that may be the issue

Example of a single value (I just want the column to show "I'm thinking this...")

```
Comments            Ich glaube das...
Translations                                                       DE  
Race / Ethnicity                                                White
Count2                                                             91
translated          I'm thinking this because I'm nearing retireme...
```

Current code:

```
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
import xlrd
import copy

##################TRANSLATION

translator = Translator()
file = r"xxxx"
#dt2 = translator.detect(text2)

df = pd.read_excel(file, sheet_name = 'Sheet1', converters={'Comments':str}).fillna(0)

df = df[df['Comments'] != 0]


translatedList = []
for index, row in df.iterrows():
    # REINITIALIZE THE API
    translator = Translator()
    newrow = copy.deepcopy(row)
    try:
        # translate the 'text' column
        translated = translator.translate(row['Comments'], dest='en')
        newrow['translated'] = translated.text
    except Exception as e:
        print(str(e))
        continue
    translatedList.append(newrow)
df = df.assign(translatedv4 = translatedList)
```

Comment: What is your actual problem?

Comment: I want a new column that shows "I'm thinking this because I'm nearing retireme..." but currently the value is the entire block of text displayed above

Answer (score 1):

I think you have a small mistake in your code, here:

```
translatedList.append(newrow)
```

you append full row to your list, while you want to append the new value, i.e.

```
translatedList.append(translated.text)
```

But be careful, in case of any exception lenght of translatedList will be less than length of your DataFrame index. Probably you should do something like this:

```
try:
    # translate the 'text' column
    translated = translator.translate(row['Comments'], dest='en')
    translatedList.append(translated.text)
except Exception as e:
    print(str(e))
    translatedList.append('ERRROR')
    continue
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not quite sure about your problem, so I hope this is what you're looking for. I do think you're not approaching it in the best way however. Generally with pandas, you'll want to try to vectorize your solutions or create a function that you pass to `df.apply`. Here are three solutions with increasing complexity. The first one uses a lambda function, which works but it doesn't handle exceptions. The second one creates a normal function, which allows us to do that easily. The last solution ratelimit and tqdm which are nice when working with API's and dataframes.

## Solution 1, without exception handler

```
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'German': ['ich glaube das', 'schadenfreude', 'schnappsidee']
})

translator = Translator()

df['English'] = df['German'].apply(
    lambda sent: translator.translate(sent, dest='en', src='de').text
)

print(df)

           German         English
0  ich glaube das  I believe that
1   schadenfreude   malicious joy
2    schnappsidee   snapping idea
```

## Solution 2, with exception handler

```
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd

def get_trans(sent):
    try:
        return translator.translate(sent, dest='en', src='de').text
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'German': ['ich glaube das', 'schadenfreude', 'schnappsidee', np.nan]
})

translator = Translator()

df['English'] = df['German'].apply(get_trans)

print(df)

'float' object is not iterable
           German         English
0  ich glaube das  I believe that
1   schadenfreude   malicious joy
2    schnappsidee   snapping idea
3             NaN             NaN
```

## Solution 3, with ratelimit and tqdm

When working with API's, I can really recommend the fantastic [ratelimit](https://pypi.org/project/ratelimit/) library. It can help you not ask for too many requests, and handle exceptions. I also added tqdm for a progress bar. This is nice if you have a lot of data.

```
from googletrans import Translator
import pandas as pd
from ratelimit import limits, sleep_and_retry
from tqdm.autonotebook import tqdm
# from tqdm import tqdm  <- use this instead if you're not using jupyter

FIFTEEN_MINUTES = 900

tqdm.pandas()

@sleep_and_retry
@limits(calls=15, period=FIFTEEN_MINUTES)
def get_trans(sent):
    try:
        return translator.translate(sent, dest='en', src='de').text
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        return np.nan

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'German': ['ich glaube das', 'schadenfreude', 'schnappsidee', np.nan]
})

translator = Translator()

df['English'] = df['German'].progress_apply(get_trans)

print(df)

           German         English
0  ich glaube das  I believe that
1   schadenfreude   malicious joy
2    schnappsidee   snapping idea
3             NaN             NaN
```